# Popping a dialog when AsyncTask completes

Tags: dialog, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask that I call from the main thread, and I wish to pop a dialog out when it completes. Other than putting the dialog code in OnPostExecute(), is there a way where I can put it in the main activity code instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Just write a function to showdialog anywhere in the activity and invoke it from onPostExecute(). Post your code pls to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an interface for that. It is simple and forward:
 1- create a new interface:

```
public interface IShowPopup {
    public void showPopup(String title, string message);
}
```

2 - implement that interface in your activity:

```
... MyActivity extends Activity implements IShowPopup {
        ...
        public void showPopup(String title, String message) {
            // create a DialogAlert here.
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage(message);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.app_license_title);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

            // show dialog.
            dialog.show();
        }
        ...
     }
```

3 - in your task you keep an instance of the activity:

```
 ...MyTask extends AsyncTask<...> {
        private IShowPopup iShowPopup ;
        // get the interface from constructor.
        public MyTask(IShowPopup isp) {
            this.iShowPopup = isp;
        }
```

4 - use the interface in your onPostExecute:

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(??) {
    // get some title and message.
    iShowPopup.showPopup(title, message);
}
```

That should be it!